# Regex to separate IIF clauses in groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am trying to get a regex that separates the parts of a IIF made in VB to convert it to a RoR if. The string that I am trying to convert is this one:

```
Var007>2,IIF(Var133=2 OR Var133=3,'',Var132+IIF(Var123=2,Var122+IIF(Var113=2,Var112,0),0)+IIF(Var007>3,IIF(Var143=3,Var142,0),0)),''
```

And the regex that I am developing is this one:

```
(.{1,}),(?![^\(]*\))(.{1,}),(?![^\(]*\))(.{1,})
```

I want to get this:

- `Var007>2`
- `IIF(Var133=2 OR Var133=3,'',Var132+IIF(Var123=2,Var122+IIF(Var113=2,Var112,0),0)+IIF(Var007>3,IIF(Var143=3,Var142,0),0))`

Now , I am getting this because can´t select a group between brackets.

- `Var007>2,IIF(Var133=2 OR Var133=3,'',Var132+IIF(Var123=2,Var122+IIF(Var113=2,Var112,0),0)+IIF(Var007>3`
- `IIF(Var143=3,Var142,0),0))`

You can see it on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/8LvsGb8H3u).

This are a few examples of the possible string:

```
Var007>0,IIF(Var002=0,0, ((Var111*Var112)*CaracteristicaArticulo('Var002','Kilos M2')*(1+(CaracteristicaArticulo('Var002','Porcentaje Rozamiento')/100)))+IIF(Var022=1,Var112*0.800,0)+(Var112*0.339)),''
Var007>1,IIF(Var110=0,IIF(Var025=0 OR Var025=1 OR Var025=39 OR Var025=2,20,IIF(Var025=3 OR Var025=4,21,IIF(Var025=5 OR Var025=6 OR Var025=28 OR Var025=29,22,IIF(Var025=7 OR Var025=8 OR Var025=9 OR Var025=10,24,IIF(Var025=12,26,IIF(Var025=11 OR Var025=14 OR Var025=16 OR Var025=17,27,' ')))))),''),''
```

There won't be single quotes inside string literals.

Please I need your help ;)

Comment: Try [`(?:\w+(?:(\((?:[^()]++|\g<1>)*\)))|[^,])+`](http://rubular.com/r/h0UawQd7P4)

Comment: Doesn´t work, It only matches the second group, doesn´t creates a group for each part. Thank you.

Comment: It works, show me your code. You are not using the regex correctly.

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/OjyKLtXl5o you can see it here group 1 and 3 are empty.

Comment: Last question: can there be string literals inside parentheses?

Comment: yes, you can find string literals that are meant to be a API petition.

Comment: Ok, you should better write a parser for this, it is rather a hard task for a single regex. It can be written, but it will be too long/unreadable. Look, [it is easy to get trapped](https://regex101.com/r/pA8HrM/1).

Comment: I know how to do the next step but I can´t separate the IIF in 3 parts, if you can solve this it would be great. Thanks

Comment: Can there be regular C string literals or if not, what kind of string literals? Please provide exact specs.

Comment: I have edited the question to show you more examples.

Comment: That does not help. If you have a `'` inside a string literal, is it escaped with a backslash or another single quote? `'G\'uia V-15'` or `'G''uia V-15'`? AND: can there be `"G\"uia V-15"` / `"G""uia V-15"`?

Comment: The problem is that I can´t change the strings that I am receiving. Forget the last example because it is solved with other functionality.

Comment: I understand you cannot change them, but what is their format? How are literal quotes represented?

Comment: They are strings, it´s Visual Basic Code that I have to transform to RoR and the only solution I have found is to do it with regex.

Comment: Ok, so it is Visual Basic? But the string literals in VB are defined with double quotes, while you show single ones. Please answer my question: If you have a `'` inside a string literal, is it escaped with a backslash or another single quote? `'G\'uia V-15'` or `'G''uia V-15'`? AND: can there be `"G\"uia V-15"` / `"G""uia V-15"`?

Comment: No, the string is literally what you see. I receive a string like this: "IIF(Var007>0,IIF(Var002=0,0, ((Var111*Var112)*CaracteristicaArticulo('Var002','Kilos M2')*(1+(CaracteristicaArticulo('Var002','Porcentaje Rozamiento')/100)))+IIF(Var022=1,Var112*0.800,0)+(Var112*0.339)),'')"

Comment: BUT if there is a single quote inside? How is it defined? Or can you guarantee there are NEVER single quotes inside the string literals?

Comment: What I do is to extract the first "IIF( and the last )" with a regex and the next step is what I am asking you.

Comment: So, there cannot be quotes inside `'Guia V-15'`? Please add this detail to the question.

Comment: No. There will not be quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to parse strings like this with regex, but your requirements are not that complex in this case.

Here is a solution that will match "tokens" that consist of 1 or more occurrences of 1+ word chars followed with a balanced amount of `(...)` and having `'...'` substrings inside  (with possible `(` or `)`), or chars other than `,`:

```
s = "Var007>2,IIF(Var133=2 OR Var133=3,'',Var132+IIF(Var123=2,Var122+IIF(Var113=2,Var112,0),0)+IIF(Var007>3,IIF(Var143=3,Var142,0),0)),''"
rx = /
  (                                      # Group 1, what we need to extract
   (?:                                   # A non-capturing group acting as a container
      \w+                                # 1 or more word chars
          ( # Group 2 (technical one)
            \(                           # opening parenthesis
            (?:
               '[^']*'                   # a single quoted substring with no single quotes inside
              |                          # or
               [^()']+                   # 1 or more chars other than quote and parentheses
              |                          # or
               \g<2>                     # recurse Group 2 pattern
            )*                           # Group 2 end, can repeat 0 or more times
            \)                           # closing parenthesis
          )
     |
      [^,]                               # Any char other than a comma
   )+                                    # One or more occurrences of the alternatives in the container group
  )                                      # End of Group 1
  /x  # extended mode with all in-pattern whitespace ignored 

res = []
s.scan(rx) { |m|
    res << m[0]   # Only collect Group 1 values dropping all others
}
puts res
```

See the [Ruby demo online](https://ideone.com/Blmf6E)

Output:

```
Var007>2
IIF(Var133=2 OR Var133=3,'',Var132+IIF(Var123=2,Var122+IIF(Var113=2,Var112,0),0)+IIF(Var007>3,IIF(Var143=3,Var142,0),0))
''
```

Comment: I am trying with this now, in your example it seems to be working. Now I have to be sure that works for every string that comes from the API. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PacoGómezCapón That is why I was asking for *exact requirements*. You must post them before saying "oh-I-may-have-another-string".

Comment: I know but the API returns almost a thousand of strings like that I think that this will work but it´s not 100% sure. Thanks.